# There exists an algebra that for every linear map is derivation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, derivatives, lie-algebras, jordan-algebras

From the formal definition of [Derivation (differential algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra))
. I want know if there exists an non-trivial algebra that for every linear map on it, is a derivation.

Comment: note:  the identity map is a linear map

Comment: @J. W. Tanner: yes, this is a hidden question: there exists an algebra for can 'identity' be written as linear combination of inner derivations?

Comment: so you'd have $ab=ab+ab$ ?

Comment: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were an algebra for which every linear map is a derivation, then in particular the identity map would be a derivation.  Then we would have $ab=ab+ab$.  There is no non-trivial algebra where that is always satisfied.

Comment: Still, the algebra can be $n$-dimensional, but with trivial product,e.g., a non-trivial abelian Lie algebra.